# Assigning a string to a queue

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is any way possible to put a `String` onto a `Queue`. So I would like to put the first character of a `String` into the front of the `Queue` and so on. How would this be possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to put the first character of a string into the front of the string"? Did you mean to write queue instead of string?

Comment: yea i meant to write queue my mistake.

Comment: and what do you mean by "is a wildcard type". You mean it uses generics, or you mean it uses generics with wildcards? Show the code.

Comment: No, it uses <Character> now, at first I tried to make it <char> but that didn't work, so then I did it as a wildcard. But now I realize it should be a <Character>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String str = "foo";
Queue<Character> charsQueue = new LinkedList<Character>();
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    charsQueue.offer(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Streams you can map the String to a Character Array, and create a Queue based on this:

```
Character[] charsArray = str.chars().mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch).toArray(Character[]::new);
Queue<Character> queueStr = new LinkedList<Character>(Arrays.asList(charsArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

starting from java 1.6 LinkedList implements Queue interface, so if you're using 1.6 then you can do something like `new LinkedList<Char>(Arrays.asList(String.toCharArray()))`